# how to check the check box with dynamic Ids using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having check-box for one name. Every check-box have dynamic name ids.

If I click the name automatically the check-box should checked. But it is not happening in my code. I tried many ways.

**My code here:**

```
var checkboxId = nameid; // it will fetch the name id. 
//$('#' + checkboxId).attr('checked', true);
$('#checkboxId').prop('checked', true);
```

**Html Code:**

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Name" + item.Id.ToString(), new { id = item.Id, @class = "Names" })%>
```

Please help me how to do this process?

Comment: What yhou have in nameid ? and where you have the script?

Comment: `$('#' + nameid)` should get to the right element.

Comment: Please share the rendered HTML, not the template.

Comment: yes. it will give like id= 1524 like as `<input class="Names" id="19329" name="Name19329" type="checkbox" value="true">`

Comment: Works just peachy [here](http://jsbin.com/mefezoxace/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually The html code what i gave is wrong

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Name" + item.Id.ToString(), new { @id = item.Id, @class = "Names" })%>
```

**My Jquery Code:**

```
 var divID = "#" + Name;
$(divID).attr('checked', true);
```